# Is namekian fusion stronger than potara fusion?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

Since Universe 6 lost their potara earrings, and the 2 warriors left are namekians, and it would seem they might eventually fuse considering Champa tells them "you know what you have to do, don't you?" and they say "leave it to us, Champa sama" "We will defeat Universe 7" which would be a very optimistic thought if they rely in their current power level only which is close to Piccoro or Gohan, if they eventually fuse, how much stronger could they become? is namekian fusion stronger than potara fusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong, but considering Champa's actions, words and behaviour so far I am pretty sure that he was trying to tell them to not lose. Which could either indicate to destroying the enemies (which seems very unlikely) or waiting it out. I think he meant waiting it out since it was said in earlier episodes that if at the end of the time multiple universes have warriors left then the one with the most warriors would win. Considering their power level + max power level with any given form of boost they wouldn't come close to Kefla. Even if they used Potara earrings. This is because of the fact that they have a fixed power level due to not having saiyan blood. They can power up a little with a ki boost, but nothing close to super saiyan.

Champa is no fool. He sure as hell acts dumb and crazy but his decisions are spot on and based on the current situation. That's why he told Kale and Califa to attack instead of hiding when their power levels were raising in order to destroy Goku. Their initial strategy was to wait it out and hope to be the universe with the most numbers at the end of the tournament after Hit was fallen. But Potara happened which drove Goku to UI. The 2 Namekians will never even reach the power level of SSJ2 Goku when they fuse. With Potara they might be able to force Goku to use SSG, but they can't boost themself more and more like a saiyan, so they will stay at that level while Goku keeps evolving.

Champa knows this as well based on what he had seen. He can be pretty sly as well so he might want them to use nasty strategies in order to reduce the enemy numbers. But it is either this or waiting it out. He definitely didn't mean to tell them to fight as that would mean the loss of his universe due to Jiren and Goku still being alive. Even with depleted stamina Goku requires only a couple of taks in order to recover again to use UI. This is based on the time that passed in the tournament (not episodes) between the first and second UI. Champa knowing this as well would not tell his warriors to fight against such a threat.

**Edit:**
I just noticed that I had never answered your question and was simply just explaining the situation. The answer is no. Namekian fusion isn't stronger than Potara. Based on Piccolo x Nail fusion with the power levels before and after we can conclude that this formula is **fusion power = (A+B)*7(raw estimate)**. Potara earrings scale far bigger and are known as the strongest type of fusion. When Vegito was introduced in DBZ we could see that it was far stronger than SSJ3 Goku. SSJ3 in general has a rough multiplier of x400 (some sources say x1000) from the base form. Since we have to consider Vegeta as well in the fusion we can conclude that the actual multiplier is **at least** x100 with Potara earrings. I couldn't find any credible source to explain the multiplier but based on before and after scenes and known multiplier for SSJ states we can give a raw estimate. Anyway Potara is far stronger than a namekian fusion. The most reasonable formula that I found for it was baseform A x baseform B. Some others said that it draws out max potentional achieved by each user and multiplies that by 400. But these aren't official sources.

So all in short, **no**, Namekian fusion isn't stronger than Potara fusion.

Comment: I agree with you that for what we've seen up to know, namekian fusion isnt as strong as potara fusion. But Dragon Ball writers have a habit of ignoring things like that to keep the story going and I feel like this might be one of those situations

Comment: So I'll wait a little until Universe 6 gets eliminated to see if this is the case or not, or I could be accepting a wrong answer

Comment: I completely agree with you. So far all Namekians fusions matched the formula, but in super plenty of things were changed slightly and majorily so waiting it out will most likely indeed proof me right or wrong... that if they will fuse at all (I hope they will).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Gohan seems to be stronger than the two Namekians as he was fighting in his base form and his mystic/ultimate form makes him significantly stronger and might very likely bring his power probably to the same leve as Kale and maybe even close to the level of android 17.

What Champa was trying to say was that, he hoped the Namekians knew what was at stake and would do whatever necessary to survive.

Them saying "We will defeat Universe 7", is more or less similar to Ribrianne claiming to be stronger than Goku, or the Universe 9 fighters trying to challenge Universe 7.

Assuming they do happen to fuse, they still wouldn't be on par with any god tier character(UI Goku, Jiren) , or even high tier characters like (Vegeta, Toppo, Freiza). I highly doubt they'd even be stronger than mid tier characters like 17 and Gohan, based on the fact that base gohan was able to easily keep up with them. So ideally speaking, the only 2 fighters they would be able to over power from Universe 7 would be, Picollo and Android 18.

With regard to the comparison between the Namekian Fusion and the Potara fusion, I recommend you have a look at my answer here [All possible fusions/absorbtions and their multipliers](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/43453/all-possible-fusions-absorbtions-and-their-multipliers/43456#43456) . Where I  have explained as to why the potara fusion is a lot superior than all other fusions. And also why the namekian fusion is possibly the weakest form of fusion out of all the ones we have seen on the show.

Answer (score -3):

Namekian fusion is very weak. Its boost is roughly x300 ~ x400 (i.e ~3,500 PL -> ~1,210,000 PL).

Whereas Potara fusion is at least x(400 + unknown constant) boost.

Comment: Source of reference?

Comment: Dude what? Where is this equation coming from?

Comment: The first one is Piccolo power level before training in Kaiosama's planet divided by the stated power level of Piccolo after fusing with Nail. But he's missing having into account the power level of Nail (which was stated to be 42,000 in the manga I believe) and he's also missing Piccolo raised his power level in Kaiosama's planet. If we use this logic , Piccolo and Nail power level together is probably around 80,000 to 120,000 (estimated power levels for Piccolo after training are around 40,000 to around 80,000) and the namekian fusion would be a between x10 to x15  multiplier

Comment: x300-400 is not considered weak at all. But apart from that, where do those numbers come from? From what I know the namekian fusion boost at most to x10. After doing some digging I hit up this thread which sums it up pretty well about what the multiplier is like: http://www.neoseeker.com/forums/88/t2163609-namekian-fusion-multiplier-confusion/

Comment: This is incorrect. The Namekian fusion is (Namek A+ Namek B) * 7.08. There is no actual multiplier with regard to the Potara fusion. We just know for a fact that it is the strongest form of fusion and superior to all other fusions.